# Resolve a contradictory conflict in /etc tree (mercurial-based etckeeper)

Tags: mercurial, etckeeper

I have an `/etc` file tree which is managed by `etckeeper`, based on Mercurial.
After running `apt-get dist-upgrade`, I want to revision the changes which have been applied by the upgrade.

However, when doing

```
hg add $(hg status . --unknown --no-status)
```

I get this conflict:

```
abort: file 'php5/apache2/conf.d' in dirstate clashes with 'php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini'

hg status php5/apache2/conf.d
```

gives me:

```
! php5/apache2/conf.d
? php5/apache2/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
? php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
? php5/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini
? php5/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini
```

This looks contradictory to me: If the directory `php5/apache2/conf.d` would be missing, how could it contain new (unversioned) files?!

How can I resolve this conflict?

(Debian Linux, upgraded 7.11 to 8.5; Mercurial 3.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the missing `(/etc/)php5/apache2/conf.d` was a symlink which was replaced by a directory.

I put the directory in a tar archive, just to be safe, and tried `hg revert php5/apache2/conf.d`, which yielded (German version; sorry, I forgot to repeat with `LANG=C`):

```
Abbruch: Konnte symbolische Verknüpfung auf '../conf.d' nicht erzeugen: File exists: '/etc/php5/apach2e/conf.d'
```

If `hg revert` tries to create a symbolic link, I assume the missing resource was a symlink.  This little dance did the trick (twice - for `php5/apache2` and `php5/cli`):

```
mv conf.d conf.d-tmp
hg rm conf.d
hg commit conf.d -m 'Conflict resolution, part 1'
mv conf.d-tmp conf.d
hg commit conf.d -m 'Conflict resolution, part 2'
```

After doing this I was able to add all remaining "unknown" resources, and to remove all remaining "deleted" resources:

```
hg add $(hg status -un)
hg rm $(hg status -dn)
```